# Google BigQuery - parse_timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

Having a difficult time parsing this particular expression:

`'2021-01-06 01:16:04.0880000 +00:00'`

I have tried the below whole consulting the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) for timestamp:

```
select parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%E*S %Ez', '2021-01-06 01:16:04.0880000 +00:00')
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%E*S` also includes the seconds (`%S`) so you can use the following instead:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S %Ez', '2021-01-06 01:16:04.0880000 +00:00')
-- Output: 2021-01-06 01:16:04.088 UTC
```