# Google BigQuery removing leading 0s on fractional part of timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

BigQuery TIMESTAMP datatype has microsecond precision, 6 fractional seconds.

When I run the following query

```
SELECT CAST("2020-06-02 07:00:53.001000" AS TIMESTAMP) AS as_timestamp
```

I would expect  `2020-06-02 07:00:53.001000 UTC`
What I get instead is ...  `2020-06-02 07:00:53.1000 UTC`

As there is 2 leadings 0's, BigQuery omits them for some reason. Can anyone help me out at all to stop BigQuery omitting these leadings 0s ? I'm trying to calculate some time differences between timestamps and it's throwing my calculations off.

Thanks

Comment: I think this may be a bug.  The following two alternatives should be viable:
`SELECT 
    CAST("2020-06-02 07:00:53.001000" AS TIMESTAMP) AS as_timestamp,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%F %R:%E*S", "2020-06-02 07:00:53.001000"),
    timestamp("2020-06-02 07:00:53.001000")`
however they are both returning the `.1000` ms value.  This question from a few months ago is similar, and seemed to work then:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127893/google-bigquery-parse-timestamp

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. I tried many different things and there is nothing obvious at all in the documentation. 

If I do `SELECT CAST("2020-06-02 07:00:53.010000" AS TIMESTAMP) AS as_timestamp` I get only 5 fractional parts as there is only one leading zero. 

I could make a solution based on knowing there should always be micro precision  but it feels horrible

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe this is a UI bug, not a BigQuery Engine's

Below two proves for this

- Prove 1
  Look at JSON tab to see actual value returned by BQ

[image]

- Prove 2

I run same query in another BigQuery IDE ( I personally use Goliath BigQuery IDE) and you can see correct result

[image]

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I am trying to use the values within a user defined function after turning them into JS Date objects. They just turn into the wrong values.


`CREATE TEMP FUNCTION returnUpTime(data ARRAY<STRUCT<timestamp TIMESTAMP,`

 `let timeDiff =  new Date(data[i].timestamp) - new Date(data[i - 1].timestamp);`

`returnUpTime(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(timestamp`

Comment: Actually, It is working correctly in the UDF, I was mistaken. Thank you for your help